# Objective-c, method declaration in .h and private property in .m confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, properties, private

I am reading a [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/blocks-and-table-view-cells-on-ios--mobile-22982) tutorial in which he declared a method in `cell .h file` which accept a `block` but did **not** implement the method in `.m class`, he declared a `private property` with same name as `method` `@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^didTapButtonBlock)(id sender);`

what is this practice? only declaring a method in .h and making a private property in .m

I tried to do it simply like this

I created a method in .h file

```
-(void)xyz:(NSString*)string;
```

in .m file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
```

But Xcode giving warning `Method definition for 'xyz' not found`

Kindly tell what is going behind the scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's exposing the setter method for the block variable, but keeping the getter private, if you notice, the method have the word `set`, which is the setter method for a property

This is how you can do the same:

```
-(void)setXyz:(NSString*)xyz;
```

and in .m:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *xyz;
```

This way is to make sure other class cannot get the property instance, but can give it value